# Проблема с WP при переносе БД с Windows на Mac

Tags: wordpress

Возникла проблема в Wordpress c переносом БД с Openserver(windows) на MAMP(Mac).
Простое export/import не помогает.

Если запустить сайт локально - корректно отображается на Windows, затем, когда экспортируем базу с Windows и импортируем в Mac, и запускаем сайт локально на Mac, то у нас некорректно указывается адрес сайта.

**ошибка** - Не удается получить доступ к сайту.

Пример в адресной строке:

windows - test/

Mac - test/test/

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress/767562#767562

Comment: Просто криво перенесли) вот и все